# Question from Relative Error

Tags: homework-and-exercises, space

Q -A satellite orbits Earth at a height of 560 km. In many computations, the Earth-Sun distance of 1.5 X 10⁸ km is used to approximate the distance of satellite from the Sun. What is the maximum relative error of this approximation?
Please explain the main concept in detail.

Comment: We don't solve homework exercises at this site. What is your specific conceptual difficulty? What work have you tried?

Comment: Its not my homework. See the question clearly. I have doubt regarding the concept only that is going to be applied here.

Answer (score 0):

If the distance between the earth and the sun is given as $1.5 \times 10^8$ km then you can assume this figure has a precision of $\pm 0.05 \times 10^8$ km, which is $\pm 5$ million km. If the satellite height is stated to be $560$ km then you can assume this figure has a precision of $\pm 5$ km. I'll let you take it from there.